# How to reprocess Kafka Topic everyday for job processing?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have requirement to reprocess all the message available on kafka topic during the End of day Job. Any best way to implement with Kafka Topic?

I have implemented with StateStore, but StateStore has its own challenges and not production ready product.

Alternate way is to save the data into RDBMS using kafka-connect and reprocess them, but trying to build something with kafka topics and avoiding using any other interaction

Comment: Statestores are certainly production ready, although with some configuration; I've seen several projects that use them. More importantly, how do you define "end of day"? What timezone are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

On the lowest level, you could just use a KafkaConsumer with offset policy `auto.offset.reset=earliest` (if you really want to process all messages).

Also, there's a `timestamp -> offset` Consumer API if you'd rather do the processing for the last time (alternatively you could set up retention to 24h, but then it's imprecise magic depending on your server, so I'd find pure API approach more reliable/predictable).